# Setting colours to multiple lines in matplotlib (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph computed from matplotlib, containing six plotted lines, and I want to know what I'm doing wrong for assigning each of my lines a unique colour.

I've got a list for the colours using hex codes, and each listx in "lists" contains the y axis data for each line:

```
colours = ["#ffa500", "#008000", "#ff0000", "#800080", "#7f6000", "#ffa7b6"]
lists = [list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, list6]
```

and I'm trying to assign each colour for each line:

```
for c in range(len(colours)):
    for l in lists:
        plt.plot(x, l, colours[c])
```

What I'm getting currently is every line being assigned pink (the last entry in the colours list), rather than each colour corresponding to each list (e.g. list2 needs color #008000).

I'm relatively new to programming, so if someone can explain what's wrong and how I can fix this that would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You have nested for loop. So you are plotting every list with every color, you have 36 plots in total. The last color is drawn on top of all previous ones. 
Also your code is not runnable as is, please provide a full example as discussed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is probably happening in your code is because you are looping through your colours list index and then for each index in your colours you are looping through lists.

So what will happen is you will get to the end of your colours list indexes (pink) and then loop through lists plotting each using that colour.

To fix this (if your colours and lists lists will always be the same length) do something like:

```
for x in range(len(colours)):
    plt.plot(x, lists[x], colours[x])
```

I hope this works for you.